# Entity Framework CodeFirst, Add Dbset to DbContext, programmatically

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, dbset

how can i Add DbSet to my dbContext class, programmatically.
[

```js
        public class MyDBContext : DbContext 
        {
          
            public MyDBContext() : base("MyCon")
            {
               

                Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDBContext>());

            }
       
//Do this part programatically:
            public DbSet<Admin> Admins { get; set; }        
            public DbSet<MyXosh> MyProperty { get; set; }

        }
```

][1]

i want to add my model classes by ((C# Code-DOM)) and of course i did. but now i have problem with creating DbSet properties inside my Context class ...

Comment: You can't. The DbSet's are properties of the DbContext, and you can't expand existing objects at runtime. However, you can get the DbSet's of any mapped types using the context.Set<T>() property.

Comment: so how can i create table dynamically  if i cant create dbset inside db context ?...have you any solution for this?

Comment: you can go without DbSet's entirely, override your OnModelCreating and map only those types you are actually going to use.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Yes you are right ..I did it

Answer (score 2):

yes i did!..
this: https://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/

And this: [Create Table, Run Time using entity framework Code-First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807101/create-table-run-time-using-entity-framework-code-first?answertab=votes#tab-top)

are solution. no need to dispute with **dbSets** directly. it just works by do some thing like that:

```
  public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{

    public MyDBContext() : base("MyCon")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDBContext>());
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
        var theList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                  .Where(t => t.Namespace == "FullDynamicWepApp.Data.Domins")
                  .ToList();
        foreach (var item in theList)
        {
            entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(item)
                           .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice solution but why didn't you just create also MyDBContext with codedom?

Comment: this solution is better, it doesn't need amount of code and generate a new dbcontext class for each model creating. @bubi

Answer (score 1):

For those using **EF Core** that stubble here:

The code below is only for one table with the generic type. If you want more types you can always pass them through the constructor and run a cycle.

```cs
public class TableContextGeneric<T> : DbContext where T : class
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    //public virtual DbSet<T> table { get; set; }

    public TableContextGeneric(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var entityMethod = typeof(ModelBuilder).GetMethods().First(e => e.Name == "Entity");

        //the cycle will be run here
        entityMethod?.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T))
            .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString); // can be anyone 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an usage example please?

Comment: create a database based on certain types. Pratical example: Automatic invoice database creation based on the fields that you pass them. Using the code above, you just need to have this types and you can create a database.