# Create Table, Run Time using entity framework Code-First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Is that possible to create table  in run time by using **EF** Code-first? 
i could create my models class in run time by using  C# CodeDOM(reflection) but i couldn't set the **dbSet** properties of my **Dbcontext** class in run time. 
whats your idea?
whats the best solution to create table dynamically in run time?...
some ones said to my that the only way is using classic **ADO.Net**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes,you can do that.

You can do that using Finding the Classes :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class PersistentAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Now you can add some logic to the `OnModelCreating` method of your `context` to scan assemblies and add any classes with the `[Persist]` attribute as shown below.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");

    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
      var entityTypes = assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t =>
          t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PersistentAttribute), inherit: true)
          .Any());

      foreach (var type in entityTypes)
      {
        entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type)
          .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use below mentioned code based data migration method hence automatically change the database when new classes or properties are added to the model.

```
var config = new DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext> { AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true };
var migrator = new DbMigrator(config);
migrator.Update();
```

You can read more about this : [**Dynamically Building A Model With Code First**](https://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/)

**Update :** How to Query a Dynamic Table ?

```
public IEnumerable<ResultTableTemplate> GetResultsFromTable(string tableName) {
    using (var context = new MyContext()) {
        var query = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<ResultTableTemplate>("SELECT " +
            "ALL_THOSE_COLUMN_NAMES... " +
            "FROM " + tableName;

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

See this for more : [**Querying data using Entity Framework from dynamically created table**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896843/querying-data-using-entity-framework-from-dynamically-created-table)

Comment: but now ...how can i do query link when i dont have a dbContext Without any DbSet????   @Sam

Comment: please see the **Update**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817703/hot-to-use-dbcontext-when-there-is-no-dbset-inside-that-for-query?noredirect=1#comment66933877_39817703 ...what about this ? @Sampath

Comment: hope that too will work.You can accept both solutions then :D

Comment: yes i had to press that Green sign excuse me :)...  i'm  just a new in stackoverflow  :D

Answer (score 3):

finally to have a query on a dbContext which doesn't have any DbSet<>...

using this:

```
var x = Db.Set<YourModelType>().ToList();
```

it's perfectly working if type and name of your **model classes** be much as like  their related **Tables**  name on **database**.(it has to be)

special Tnx for @Sampath