# How to use DbContext when there is no DbSet<> inside that, for query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I'm using **Entity Framework Code-First** and this is my **DbContext**. As you see there is nothing about **DbSet<>** properties and all of that will provide from my model classes which are providing by C# `CodeDOM`. I'm creating my **Tables** dynamically by using **Code-First**.

```
    public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{

    public MyDBContext() : base("MyCon")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDBContext>());
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
        var theList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                  .Where(t => t.Namespace == "FullDynamicWepApp.Data.Domins")
                  .ToList();
        foreach (var item in theList)
        {
            entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(item)
                           .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

but now I don't know how can I write my **query Linq** without any **DbSet<>** inside my **DbContext**? make instance of my DbContext and use which property?

```
 MyDBContext Db = new MyDBContext();
        Db.What???????
```

How can I write my **CRUD operation** s in these circumstances?

Comment: Charles Mager's answer is correct and the only way if you do not want to go to the underlying ObjectContext or another DbContext. Just wanted to mention you should always (when possible) wrap your DbContext's in using block, so they can get disposed of properly.

Comment: You certainly can use Charles' answer, but why not just add theDbSet<> properties to your MyDBContext class, at least for the entity types you intend to directly query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DbContext.Set<TEntity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set%60%601) method will return a `DbSet<TEntity>` for the given type, e.g:

```
Db.Set<Entity>().Add(entity);
```