# Change Entity Framework Code First class at runtime C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Is it possible to change entity framework code-first class at runtime by reflection? Or even generate it?

Or what happens to database if we change those classes at runtime?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about adding and removing properties at runtime?

Comment: The database migration is done once when you start the application/access the DbContext the first time.

Comment: Yes,I want to know if changing properties is possible.

Comment: But i need to remove a class at runtime from DbContext class or add into it.

Comment: No, not at runtime.  If you want to change an EF model, you need to do it before you compile.

Comment: In case to help someone I found a helpful answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807101/create-table-run-time-using-entity-framework-code-first)